# Javascript transitional page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

My question is pretty straightforward. How to create a transitional scroll which looks like the one here:
http://eee.asus.com/eeepad/transformer-prime/features/

Comment: wait, thats a duplicate. I can't find it by now, have you searched for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses a scrollAnimate jquery plugin to animate elements on the page - you can find this plugin at https://github.com/Cardume/scrollAnimate

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. For anyone else who needs more on this topic you can check this tutorial its quite helpful: